# Separating view part from servlet code

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am a beginner in JSP. I am doing a project in that I have to separate the view part, i.e. `out.println` statements from `Servlet` code. How do I perform this? Please suggest.

This is controller servlet the request will come through *index.jsp* page.

```
request.setAttribute("ival", n);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("ControllerServlet");
rd.forward(request, response);`enter code here`
```

My *ControllerServlet.java*:

```
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private String temp = null;
    private int k;
    public String gettemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        k=(Integer)request.getAttribute("ival"); // value is coming from index.jsp page

        try {
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet ControllerServlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");           

            switch (k) {
                case 1:
                    temp = "Monday";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    temp = "tuesday";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    temp = "Wednesday";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    temp = "thrusday";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    temp = "friday";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    temp = "saturday";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    temp = "sunday";
                    break;
            }                

           /*
            out.println(temp);
            out.println("value of n is ="+ k);
            out.println("<a href =\"index.jsp\">next </a>");    
            */
            request.setAttribute("temp", temp);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("SucessView.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");   
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

In above code I want to perform this operation through separate JSP page "SuccessView.jsp":

```
out.println(temp);
out.println("value of n is ="+ k);
out.println("<a href =\"index.jsp\">next </a>");
```

Please suggest how to perform this?

For this I have done this, but this is not working.

Please suggest the other way to fetch temp value .

Comment: _for this i have done this, but this is not working._ Please rephrase.

Comment: As a side note: **DO NOT** try to write something to the output, **after** calling [*RequestDispatcher#forward()*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)), because it already committed to the output. It is either writing to the output using your *PrintWriter* **OR** using `forward` (or `include`) on the dispatcher object. Also read this: [Include vs. Forward of the Servlet RequestDispatcher](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Include-vs-Forward-of-the-Servlet-RequestDispatcher).

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is related to [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern). This tutorial could be useful to you: [The Model View Controller (MVC) Architecture: Integrating Servlets and JSP](http://www.java-programming.info/tutorial/pdf/csajsp2/14-MVC.pdf). It is from the popular [Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your servlet should not include HTML code.

The view is done in JSP.

When you submit your form, you send it to a servlet. Upon completion of the form data treatment, it will return to a JSP page again to show the result.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/MyServlet" method="post">
<input type="text" name="myName">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your servlet "MySerlet" you can retireve the name or any other field from the form, and perform the business logic (and database insert/update/delete) as required.

At the end of the servlet use a `response.sendRedirect("/myThanksPage.jsp");` to redirect to your thanks page.

Comment: +1 for the general solution. But one **important note** though: in such scenarios, it is more common/better to **forward** to the JSP, than to redirect. When redirecting it will be a **totally new request**, so, **if** you have added/set some [**request attributes**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) to the initial request, that you are going to use in you "Thank You" JSP page, they will be lost!

Comment: The problem (for me) of the forward is that for maintenance (debugging) it's not clear in which code you actually are... That's why I prefer the redirect, even if it generates an additional network roundtrip. But it's a personal preference.